# I have videos & images with total size of approximately 500 MB. How can I manage IT?

Tags: android, memory-management, apk

I have to create one application which has use of lots of videos & images. Total size of all the videos & images which are used in application is approximately 500 Mb. Whole application is depend on this videos & images.

I know that android market supports only 50 Mb max. size of apk. I have no Idea that how can I use videos & images in my application. If I put it into drawable then the apk size increase to 500 MB and I know that it is not possible to install 500 MB apk file to mobile device.

If I put this videos & images to the server then It takes so much time to load every time.

Anybody have solution for this problem that How can I manage this size of video and images in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to solve this is to put the data on a server and download it to the SD-Card after startup of the App. Explain it to the user in the market listing that he needs the videos to use the App and be sure to check what kind of data connection your user is using. You can then warn the user if she tries to download the 500MB through a mobile connection.

Comment: hii but how can i download the 500 mb file in sdcard is there any special library

Answer (score 1):

As of 3/5/2012, Android Market (aka Google Play) is supporting the attachment of up to two "expansion files" of up to 2 Gigabytes each.  Your APK must still be under 50 MB, but the attached files can total an additional 4GB.

Whether the resulting SD card storage requirements are acceptable is now between you and your users; Google is stepping out of the way and letting the *other* "market" decide!

Google's announcement of this policy update appears here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user the first time they run it that they need to download the items and store on the SD card. Then references them because you know where you put them on the card.